# Handlling GWT call failure

Tags: gwt

Hello I have a piece of code in GWT, A senior colleage of mine has written this code.

```
public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

    if (caught instanceof RuntimeException) {

        if (caught instanceof StatusCodeException
            && caught.getMessage().contains(
                "<title>Error 500 unAuthorized</title>")) {
            MessageBox
                .alert("Session has been expired. Press Ok to redirect to Login page.");
            History.newItem(HistoryToken.INDEX_PAGE.toString());
         } else {
        MessageBox
            .alert("An exception has occured.Press Ok to continue.");
         }

    } else if (caught instanceof InvocationException) {
        MessageBox
            .alert("Sorry... Some error occured while reaching to server.");

    }
}
```

What are the chances of executing `else if (caught instanceof InvocationException) {` block when call failed on server ?

I think `else if (caught instanceof InvocationException)` will not get executed in any case.
Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because InvocationException is a subclass of RuntimeException (as the [docs](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/InvocationException.html) say), you are correct.

BTW, is there any reason your senior colleague does a string comparison on getMessage instead of checking the status code with getStatusCode()? ([See here](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/StatusCodeException.html#getStatusCode%28%29))

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The guy has left the company.